# How to check if a specific programm is installed?

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, installed-programs, checkinstall

Simple Question, I want to check if a `specific programm = sp` is installed on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I dont want to for `sudo apt-get sp` and I can't check all folders.
Is there a fast and good way?

Comment: If the program was in .deb from, then dpkg will tell you `dpkg -l | grep -i sp` . If it wasn't in .deb from, try to locate its files `sudo updatedb` & `locate -i sp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your name `sp` refers to a package name, the correct procedure, imho, is to use

```
dpkg --get-selections sp
```

(`dpkg -l` provides an output adapted to the terminal width, and so can truncate package names, and it also reports non installed packages for which still exist config files)

If you name refer to an application name, the following could be useful (if using the default `bash` shell)

```
type sp
```