# How to programmatically check if getopts is installed? If not, install it

Tags: bash

Running Ubuntu 16.04
I want to install (programmatically) getopts if it is not installed.

After this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332438/how-to-check-if-a-specific-programm-is-installed) I am doing something like this:

```
GETOPTS=getopts

if [$GETOPTS==""] 
   then
   echo "Installing getopts"
   sudo apt-get install -y libperl4-corelibs-perl
fi
```

But it is not working.

Any Idea how to do this?

Comment: What does _"it is not working"_ exactly mean? What error message do you get? `sudo` usually asks for a password. Do you supply one? Which `getopts` do you want to install? `libperl4-corelibs-perl` contains Perl 4 libraries which is approximately 25 years old.

Comment: How about just `apt-get install PACKAGE`? This will do exactly what the title says: Check if PACKAGE is installed, if not install it, else do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to check if some tool you start from the command line is installed the following line would work:

```
if [ "`which someCommand`" = "" ]
```

The `which` command checks for the full file name of the executable of `someCommand` and if the file is **not** found the body of the `if` statement is executed.

However this assumes that `someCommand` is a command you can start from the command line (terminal etc.).

In your case you probably want to check if the file `/usr/share/perl5/getopts.pl` exists.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-regular-file-does-not-exist-in-bash) this can be done using the following check:

```
if [ ! -f /usr/share/perl5/getopts.pl ]
```

This statement will check if some file **not** exist...

Comment: this is also a good approach. It works